# How to play a stereo aiff file with pyaudio?

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, pyaudio

This plays mono aifc files, but for any stereo files I get a loud blast of static:

```
import pyaudio
import aifc

CHUNK = 1024

wf = aifc.open('C:\\path_to_file.aiff', 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

The stereo file I am testing with: https://archive.org/details/TestAifAiffFile

I'm on windows 7, if that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping every other sample does the trick. Load up the whole file into `data`, then do

```
a = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype = '<i2')
temp = a[1::2]
a[1::2] = a[::2]
a[::2] = temp
```

Then play `a` as though it were a string of audio samples rather than a numpy array. I've tested it on two different aiff files, and in both cases it preserves both channels and plays correctly.

This works probably because the file has an opposite byte order to what pyaudio expects.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on Linux, and I also get a horrible noise.

The `aifc` module seems to read the file correctly, I converted it to a NumPy array and this looks fine:

```
import numpy as np

data = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
sig = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='<i2').reshape(-1, wf.getnchannels())
```

So I guess the problem is in PyAudio or in your usage of it.

I don't know a solution but I can offer you an alternative: Use [soundfile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/) and [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/).

```
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd

data, fs = sf.read('02DayIsDone.aif')
sd.play(data, fs, blocking=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing tricky stuffs with the byte chain, you could also consider the [audioread](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/audioread/2.1.1) package instead of aifc/wave/... It decodes your audio file using whichever backend is available and regardless of the file format, it always returns buffers of 16-bit little-endian signed integer PCM data that you can feed pyaudio with.